# Dependency Injection and Callbacks With NestJS, JWT, and Socket.IO

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I'm struggling to understand how dependency injection works with callbacks. I'm using NestJS to build a Socket.IO guard using the jsonwebtoken package and am receiving the following error when I try to access an injected function within the verify function's callback:

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'configService')`

The injected function works outside of the callback, and I understand that the callback is async, and that with this function I am unable to use async/await. I also must use a callback with this function, because I'm asynchronously pulling my keys using a JWKS client.

What I wish to do is inject my Typeorm repository, access my user entity, and inject it into the Socket.IO headers. I'm able to successfully inject a manually-created object, but I need to access the repository.

I found a suggestion on the NestJS forums that involves using bindNodeCallback to create an observable, but I couldn't get this to work, and was hoping somebody could suggest a solution, or help with the code to use bindNodeCallback to get me the decoded token from the Observable so I can continue processing using regular DI structure.

Here's the guard code, and thanks in advance.

```
import {
  CanActivate,
  ExecutionContext,
  Injectable,
  UnauthorizedException,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import * as jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import * as jwks from 'jwks-rsa';
import { Observable, bindNodeCallback } from 'rxjs';

interface jwtAccessToken {
  iss: string;
  sub: string;
  aud: string[];
  iat: number;
  exp: number;
  azp: string;
  scope: string;
}

/**
 * Guard validates Auth0 token and injects user into header
 */
@Injectable()
export class WsJwtGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private configService: ConfigService) {}

  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean {
    try {
      const client = context.switchToWs().getClient();
      if (!client.handshake.auth || !client.handshake.auth.token) {
        throw new UnauthorizedException('Missing authorization header');
      }
      const token = client.handshake.auth.token.split(' ')[1];
      const jwksUri = `${this.configService.get(
        'AUTH0_DOMAIN'
      )}.well-known/jwks.json`;

      const jwksClient = jwks({
        cache: true,
        rateLimit: true,
        jwksRequestsPerMinute: 5,
        jwksUri: jwksUri,
      });

      function getKey(header, callback) {
        jwksClient.getSigningKey(header.kid, function (err, key) {
          const signingKey = key.getPublicKey();
          callback(null, signingKey);
        });
      }

      // Believe this is what I need to make things work
      const verify: (...args: any[]) => Observable<jwtAccessToken> =
        bindNodeCallback(jwt.verify) as any;

      jwt.verify(
        token,
        getKey,
        {
          issuer: [this.configService.get('AUTH0_DOMAIN')], // DI works outside of callback
          audience: ['SOME_AUDIENCE'],
          algorithms: ['RS256'],
        },
        function (err, decoded: jwtAccessToken) {
          if (err) {
            throw new UnauthorizedException('Token is invalid or expired');
          }

          // Displays token
          console.log(`Decoded token: `, decoded);

          // Attempts to log an injected function
          console.log(this.configService.get('AUTH0_DOMAIN')); // DI fails inside of callback

          //
          // Want to check here for user record and inject into
          // headers but need to dependency inject repository
          //
        }
      );
      return true;
    } catch (err) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException('Token is invalid or expired');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can I ask why you're using callbacks instead of promises or async/await?

Comment: The documentation doesn't mention the availability of either, and I've tried using async/await to see if it was possible and it produced errors. I will check again though.

Comment: Okay, not async/await, but you don't need a callback and it'll be sync. jwt.verify(token, secretOrPublicKey, [options, callback])

(Asynchronous) If a callback is supplied, function acts asynchronously. The callback is called with the decoded payload if the signature is valid and optional expiration, audience, or issuer are valid. If not, it will be called with the error.

(Synchronous) If a callback is not supplied, function acts synchronously. Returns the payload decoded if the signature is valid and optional expiration, audience, or issuer are valid. If not, it will throw the error.

Comment: The error is happening because of using a `function` callback instead of an arrow function. It's losing the lexical `this`

Answer (score 0):

I'm updating my answer to reflect a better library for solving the JWT decoding problem. I switched to 'aws-jwt-verify' and it's much simpler to use -- some of this is cribbed from the docs.

```js
import { JwtRsaVerifier } from 'aws-jwt-verify';

try {
  const verifier = JwtRsaVerifier.create({
    issuer: "https://example.com/", // set this to the expected "iss" claim on your JWTs
    audience: "<audience>", // set this to the expected "aud" claim on your JWTs
    jwksUri: "https://example.com/.well-known/jwks.json", // set this to the JWKS uri from your OpenID configuration
  });
  return await verifier.verify(token);
} catch (err) {
  this.logger.log(`[decodeToken] ${err.message}`);
}
```